# "Attempted to read or write protected memory" exception

Tags: 2010, error, publishing-site, master-page, page-layout

We ran into this error while trying to open the page /_catalogs/masterpage/Forms/AllItems.aspx. I'd been attempting to approve a page layout that I'd just updated and checked in a major version.

By today, the error was gone, but not sure what caused it and how to prevent it in the future. Here are the three errors thrown at that time by the system (from the log file):

`08/24/2011 17:11:34.05     w3wp.exe (0x2030)                           0x1EB4  Document Management Server      Document Management             52od    Medium      MetadataNavigationContext Page_InitComplete: No XsltListViewWebPart was found on this page[/_catalogs/masterpage/Forms/AllItems.aspx].  Hiding key filters and downgrading tree functionality to legacy ListViewWebPart(v3) level for this list.    a433ce5c-59de-4f69-8122-313a15679048`

`08/24/2011 17:11:34.10     w3wp.exe (0x2030)                           0x1EB4  SharePoint Foundation           Runtime                         tkau    Unexpected  System.AccessViolationException: Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.    at Microsoft.Web.CommandUI.RibbonRenderer.RenderContextualGroup(DataNode xnCtxGroup, RibbonRenderContext rrc, HtmlTextWriter writer)     at Microsoft.Web.CommandUI.RibbonRenderer.RenderRibbon(DataNode xnData, RibbonRenderContext rrc, HtmlTextWriter writer)     at Microsoft.Web.CommandUI.Ribbon.AppendRibbon(HtmlTextWriter writer, Boolean headerOnly, UInt32 initialTabScaleIndex, RibbonRenderContext rrc)     at Microsoft.Web.CommandUI.Ribbon.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.SPRibbon.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)     at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children)     at Syste... a433ce5c-59de-4f69-8122-313a15679048`

`08/24/2011 17:11:34.10*    w3wp.exe (0x2030)                           0x1EB4  SharePoint Foundation           Runtime                         tkau    Unexpected  ...m.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlForm.RenderChildren(HtmlTextWriter writer)     at System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlForm.Render(HtmlTextWriter output)     at System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlForm.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer)     at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children)     at System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlContainerControl.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)     at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children)     at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children)     at System.Web.UI.Page.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)     at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)  a433ce5c-59de-4f69-8122-313a15679048`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error occurs when an application attempts to access memory that doesn't belong to it. Windows steps in and blocks to attempt which causes .NET to throw the exception you see in the log.

You generally shouldn't see this in .NET applications because the runtime should be ensuring memory is managed safely. However **it can happen in code that runs outside the .NET Framework**, such as calls to native Windows or COM (the underlying layer of SharePoint).

As you can't reproduce the error, I personally wouldn't worry about it unless you can directly say it has caused a negative impact to your system. It looks like this happened rendering the ribbon so I don't think it's a concern. SharePoint is pretty robust and should prevent anything bad from happening to your data.

**To minimise the likelihood of such an error occurring in the future:**

1. Ensure you have the latest updates installed to the .NET Framework (via Windows Update), SharePoint (via [service packs and cumulative updates](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/ff800847.aspx)), and also any software that integrates with SharePoint.
2. Ensure your environments are as clean as possible, and don't leave features, WSP solution packages, or other software installed that doesn't have a reason to be there.

Comment: Thanks, Alex. This happened on our development server, which probably has some WSP solutions that we're not using. Some cleanup is in order :)